# Observer pattern and DAO classes with CRUD static methods

Tags: java, dao, observer-pattern

I'm reviewing some DAO classes where they are exposing CRUD static methods create(), delete() etc etc. to the program and where each DAO class implements the Observer pattern by checking for changes in the database through the Notification.java class and if one change notification is received by pulling the Object from database.

The simplified code is similar to this:

OfficeDAO.java

```
public class OfficeDAO implements PropertyChangeListener
{
    public OfficeDAO()
    {
        /* 
         * Below we add ourselves to the observers of class Notifications
         * (see observer pattern in Java) in practice we are notified
         * when one of our objects is changed by a remote client user
         */
        Notification.addChangeListener(this);
    }

    public static void create(Office office)
    {
      Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

      //... stuff with the database insertion

      Notification.notifyDatabaseChanges("ocreate-" + officeId);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the addChangeListener(this); is in the constructor but because this DAO class is used through its static methods the constructor is never called.

To fix this in the main() method of the application (inside the EDT thread by the way) there's a call like:

```
new OfficeDAO(); //ignore this, it is needed only to start the DAO constructor
```

This seemed quite hacky so I thought adding a

```
static {
  Notification.addChangeListener(this);
}
```

in the OfficeDAO.java class but of course the "this" reference is not present in a static initializer, so I'm out of solutions.
Removing the static from DAO methods is out of questions because these methods are called all over the application and are called without an instance of the class.

Is there any clean solution or workaround that I'm currently missing?

Comment: Does the PropertyChangeListener also contain only static methods that are redefined in each DAO? Can you show the code for PropertyChangeListener and the Notification class? Also, in the classic Observer pattern, it is the Observable that notifies the observers about a change in its state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAO designing is a very intricate subject, you could start reading the article by Balusc (a user on this forum) on [DAO design](http://balusc.blogspot.it/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) and in the end opt for a framework which deals with DAOs and connection management.

A very slim library which gives you a good start on correct DAO implementation is [Butterfly Persistence](http://butterfly.jenkov.com/), it will create DAOFactory and manage connection for you without having to import a 100MB Spring or Hibernate jar library.

As for adding listener and notifiers for the database operations you should completely avoid that and instead use a database which supports events notification such as Oracle or Firebird.

That way you only listen for events and the database notifies you for any changes to its tables.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a pretty messy scenario, the creation of a new object just to add a listener to the Notification seems more like an anti-pattern. My assumption is that this is part of some legacy code and not much code re-factoring is possible. I could say that since the DAO layer is acting more like a singleton , you could embed a pre created DAO instance and access this through a static reference.

```
private static OfficeDAO myDAO = new OfficeDAO(); //The constructor code remains the same
```

Comment: Yes this is some legacy code which could be refactored if I were sure of the way to do it being quite many DAOs and the project itself quite big. If I made DAOs as static I would break the Notification.addChangeListener(this); calls which are critical for the application to work properly.

Comment: @sarah.ferguson I don't think you need to make the DAO's `static`. What this answer aims to explain is that you can have a `static` reference to your DAO instead of just saying `new DAO()`; While this will make the code look less hideous, it certainly will be counter-productive. Why access static methods using a reference of a class? Your IDE will add warnings about this all over your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can change all your DAO classes to Singleton. I agree that there is no need to create a DAO instance since your DAOs don't have state and this is not an ideal solution. But again, you are not looking for an ideal solution but a cleaner hack with minimal changes required in client code. I am not sure if you are using an IoC framework in your project but if you decide to use one in the future, converting the DAO to Singleton will setup the groundwork for the same.

Let's convert OfficeDAO into a Singleton :

```
public class OfficeDAO implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private static volatile OfficeDAO INSTANCE;

    private OfficeDAO() {
        if (INSTANCE != null) {// prevent reflection attacks
            throw new InstantiationError("Illegal attempt to create more than one instance of OfficeDAO");
        }
        Notification.addChangeListener(this);
    }

    public static OfficeDAO getInstance() {
        OfficeDAO localInstance = INSTANCE;
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (OfficeDAO.class) {
                localInstance = INSTANCE;
                if (localInstance== null) {
                    INSTANCE = localInstance = new OfficeDAO();
                }
            }
        }
        return localInstance;
    }

    public void create(Office office) {
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();

        // ... stuff with the database insertion

        Notification.notifyDatabaseChanges("ocreate-" + officeId);
    }
}
```

If you change all your DAOs in a similar fashion, the only change you will have to make in the client code is to change `ClassName.staticMethod()` to `ClassName.getInstance().staticMethod()`.

Example : `OfficeDAO.getInstance().create(..)`

*****That being said, it looks your Observers are also the Subjects and this is not the classic way in which the Observer pattern is implemented. Also, you can avoid the double-check locking and resort to a singleton that is not lazily instantiated. How you implement the Singleton is a matter of your choice and not directly related to the question.

If your project starts using an Ioc framework such as Spring or Guice, you can get rid of the private constructor and the getInstance method. Your best bet then would be to change all the static methods in the DAO to instance methods and have the IoC framework create and inject the DAO's into all classes that require them. This has several advantages :

1. Most IoC frameworks allow you to decide whether only one object of a class must be provided when requested or a new objects should be provided everytime one is requested. You can therefore chose between Singleton vs non Singleton DAO's without the need to change your DAO's.
2. Your datasource could change from a database to a .csv file and you wouldn't have to change the client code that uses the DAO.
3. You can actually mock your DAO's in the service classes for unit testing.

Comment: Ok singleton is a less hacky solution, but I'd like to come with a "clean" solution since I'll be messing with lots of classes. What do you mean by "double-check locking"? Can't an observer also be a subject? is it an anti-pattern?

Comment: @sarah.ferguson The amount of changes you will make is inversely proportional to how hacky your code is. You will be messing with lots of classes with my solution but you won't be changing much in the true sense other than the way client code accesses the methods. You can read more about double check locking [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). You don't need to have a Singleton implemented this way. Search the site for different ways to implement Singleton. There is nothing wrong with an observer being a subject.